# background : url(); not working

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, stellar.js

**Details** : Using Atom File Editor with Mac OS X, Making a new site on localhost and after saving it I check changes on chrome browser. Right now i have come across a problem which causes the image to not show up on the website while i was trying to set background image of a section tag in CSS.

**Problem** : I am trying to use the stellar.js parallax plugin and for that i need to set the background property of the section tag to an image of my choice. The problem is that when i use "background : url(parallax1.png);" the image does not show up on the website and only a white blank space is shown.

*HTML File* :

```
<!-- Attempting Parallax Here -->
<section class="parallax1 pic1">
</section>
<!-- Ending Attempt Here -->
```

*CSS File* :

```
.pic1
{
  background : url(parallax1.png);
}
.parallaxcontent
{
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-size : cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Points You Should Know :

- the image parallax1.png is in the same directory and i have checked the spelling, which is correct.
- I have also tried using background-image: instead of background: .
- If i use < img src="parallax.png" /> the image shows up perfectly
- i have tried to encase parallax.png in '' as well as "".

**Any help would be appreciated**,
Thanks.

Comment: Should .parallaxcontent be .parallax1 to match your class name?

Comment: you may want to change your CSS properties to `.pic1{background-image:url("parallax1.png");}` , assuming that the image (parallax1.png) is stored in the root directory.

Comment: what settings are in that `.parallax1` class which is also applied to that element? Maybe they override the `.pic1` class?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should have some content within the section tag or you can set in .pic1 class

```
min-height:200px;
```

Comment: Thanks, after adding height the code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try `background : url("parallax1.png");`

Read more here
[CSS background Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Answer (score 0):

take a look

html

```
<section class="parallax1 pic1">
</section>
```

css

```
.pic1
{
  background: blue url("https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y6/r/QDLPxJ5bMSg.png");
  width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.parallaxcontent
{
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-size : cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xju8euun/1/)